# Error localising decimals with "," and "."

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I want a price to be a decimal and for the decimal-sign to be localised. Depending on culture, a decimal may use `,` or `.`.

For now I am doing this:

```
subItem.price.ToString("#.#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But if the price is `0` (with no decimal point), the result of that turns out to be `""` and that makes my system crash.

Is there a better pattern than `"#.#"` that might handle the `0` in a better way?

Comment: So why did you pick `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: What do you want the `0` to look like? See [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Comment: David: because i want it to handle the decimal in the right way depending on where you are in the world.

Comment: Corak: I just wanted it to be a 0 and not "" as it was with when i used "#.#". Now i use "0.#" and that writes a 0 instead of "" if the price is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `0.#`. Will display `0` if value is 0.0

Answer (score 5):

How about using [`"0"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0) instead?

```
Console.WriteLine((0).ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

prints

```
0.0
```

Your code returns empty string because from [The `"#"` custom format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx#SpecifierD)

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is
>   present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.
>   **Note that this specifier never displays a zero that is not a
>   significant digit, even if zero is the only digit in the string. It
>   will display zero only if it is a significant digit in the number that
>   is being displayed**.

By the way your title and your question says different things. Your question doesn't relevant with what number decimal separator is used when you format your value. It is all about why you get empty string when you format your `0` value.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try using:

```
subItem.price.ToString("{0:C}", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it formats your string as a currency.

Comment: I don't think OP wants currency format. He never mentioned a currency in question.

Comment: It says Subitem.Price. I would assume its a currency